# Script for checking the nologin accounts and then disable the account

Tags: linux, security

"Could you please share the scripts which does the below ?"

I have written a script that scans all the relevent logs daily, makes a list of people that have had any activity that day, and maintains database (just a text file) of users and the last time they logged in.

Then I have a second script that examines the database for dates more than x days ago, an notifies the user and administrator 2 weeks prior to locking the account. And if there are any dates more than x+y days ago, deletes the account altogether.

This seems to be working for me - but I would like to use a non-proprietary solution if one is available.

"Could you please share the scripts?"

Comment: "Could you please share the scripts?" - Show me yours and I'll show you mine.

Answer (score 0):

You do know about these, don't you?

- `last`
- `lastlog`
- `chage`
- `/var/log/wtmp`